# How do I show more than 1 row in a pop up in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, leaflet, rstudio

So basically what I have is a map where all the zipcodes are clickable. Whenever I click on a specific zipcode area I get a popup, this popup will show the name and grade of a school. 
My problem now is, that there are more than 1 schools on 1 zipcode and I want to show all schools of each zipcode in the popup.

```
 shape_and_data <- merge(zipcode, aantal_hyp, by.x="PC4", by.y="ZIPCODE_SCHOOL", duplicateGeoms=TRUE, multiple = TRUE)

 #way to make colorpalletes
 pal <- colorQuantile("YlGn", NULL, n = 5)


 state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Schoolnaam: </strong>", 
                       shape_and_data$INSTELLINGSNAAM_VESTIGING, 
                       "<br><strong>Quasi cito : </strong>", 
                       shape_and_data$quasicito)


 leaflet(data = shape_and_data) %>%
   addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
   addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(GEMEENTENUMMER), 
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               color = "#BDBDC3", 
               weight = 1, 
               popup = state_popup)
```

The area with `state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Schoolnaam: </strong>",` is the popup, as you can see it will only print out 1 schoolname.

Comment: can you add (using dput) to your post a subset of you data, enough to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the variables inside your leaflet() call:

```
leaflet(data = shape_and_data) %>%
   addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
   addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(GEMEENTENUMMER), 
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               color = "#BDBDC3", 
               weight = 1, 
               popup = paste("<strong>Schoolnaam: </strong>", 
                   shape_and_data$INSTELLINGSNAAM_VESTIGING, 
                   "<br><strong>Quasi cito : </strong>", 
                   shape_and_data$quasicito))
```